# Syntax error in MySQL Function

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to set up a MySQL function for my Mail-server. The MySQL Version is 5.1.66.

I do know what is wrong with this query. I also tried with `RETURN DOUBLE`, `READS SQL DATA`, and `DETERMINISTIC` but none of them help.

I am using PhpMyAdmin. The delimiter is set to $$. But all I get is a cryptic error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TEXT CHARSET utf8 READS SQL DATA BEGIN DECLARE mygoto VARCHAR(25' at line 3
```

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_email_alias`(
myemail VARCHAR(255)
) RETURNS TEXT CHARSET utf8
READS SQL DATA

BEGIN

DECLARE mygoto VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE sdomain VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE ddomain VARCHAR(255);

SELECT SUBSTRING(myemail, INSTR(myemail, '@')+1) INTO sdomain;

SELECT target_domain
FROM alias_domain
WHERE alias_domain = sdomain
AND active = 1
LIMIT 1
INTO ddomain;

IF ddomain IS NOT NULL THEN
SELECT REPLACE(myemail, sdomain, ddomain) INTO myemail;
END IF;
SELECT goto
FROM alias
WHERE address = myemail
AND active = 1
LIMIT 1
INTO mygoto;

IF mygoto IS NOT NULL THEN
RETURN mygoto;
END IF;

RETURN null;
END $$
```

Comment: PROCEDURE is misspelled.

Comment: Corrected. New error in Post.

Comment: If you look at the [MySQL syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html), `CREATE PROCEDURE` does not `RETURN` while `CREATE FUNCTION` does.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I really lose sight of the wood for the trees. ;)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that comes across this later:

There was originally a syntax error in the keyword `PROCEDURE`.  It was missing the final `E`.

According to the MySQL syntax, `CREATE PROCEDURE` does not `RETURN`.  However, `CREATE FUNCTION` does allow the `RETURN` in the syntax.  Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html.

Answer (score 0):

PROCEDURE" on first line is missing "E"

Comment: added the missing "E" and "READS SQL DATA" new error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TEXT CHARSET utf8 READS SQL DATA BEGIN DECLARE mygoto VARCHAR(25' at line 3

Comment: Wish could help more but don't see anything visually. Do look at BLaZuRE's comment about procedure/return. Perhaps you want Function? Also, don't know about mySql, but in SQL Server you don't do RETURNs in procedures for resultsets, just execute a query and the caller gets the results. Good luck!